# how to code in unity in C++ linux

Tags: unity, c++

I would like to avoid writing code in C# as much as possible. Unity only just recently has support for linux, and I'd like to code with C++ in unity if it is possible. How does this setup go about? How can I setup coding with C++ in unity? In windows it's possible I know that much, is it possible in linux as well?

Comment: This may answer your question, take a look please https://answers.unity.com/questions/568354/can-i-program-in-c.html

Comment: You are setting yourself up for lots of headache.

Comment: If you can do it on Windows, why would it be much different on Linux? Generally the commands are the same, just slightly different syntax. I assume you are familiar with https://github.com/jacksondunstan/UnityNativeScripting for Unity C++ scripting. The techniques it describes should be usable cross-platform.